# Dynamically adding item to TableView resulted in repeated cells

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database, reloaddata

I have a tableview that's loading data dynamically from Firebase Database. Also I have an add button that allows the user to add inside the Firebase Database after that the table view must be updated and reload the data again from firebase plus the new added item. However, I'm having an issue that the data in the table view are duplicated after adding an item. I have tried to clear the datasource array and then reloading the table view data but it is not working. This is my code:

```
  override func viewDidLoad()
{
    recipeTableView.delegate = self
    recipeTableView.dataSource = self
    // clear the array
    myRecipes.removeAll()
    // get recipes
    getRecipes()
}
```

Table view extension functions

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return myRecipes.count
    }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
         recipe = self.myRecipes[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyRecipeCell")
            as! UIMyRecipesCell
        cell.setRecipe(recipe: recipe!)
    }
```

method to get data from fire base

```
func getRecipes()
{
 self.myRecipes.removeAll()
 childRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
 for child in snapshot.children
 {
  //create the object and get the info from the fire base and finally store it MyRecipes array
 self.myRecipes.append(recipe)
 }               
  self.recipeTableView.reloadData()

            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `observeSingleEvent` instead of `observe`

```
childRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot  in 
   ////         
}
```

**OR**

```
childRef.observe(.childAdded) { snapshot  in 
   ////         
}
```

**OR**

```
childRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
   self.myRecipes.removeAll ()
   /// 
}
```

`observe` fetches all the data again every change  unlike `observeSingleEvent` that gets all the data once